# Converting a phrase into one being used by the machine leaning model

Tags: python

I am creating a medical web app that takes in audio input, converts it to text, and extracts keywords from the said text file, which is then used in an ML model. We have the text, but the problem lies in the fact that the person might say, `I have pain in my chest and legs` but the symptoms in our model are `chest_pain` or `leg_pain`.

How do we convert the different phrasing used by the user to one that matches our model features? Our basic approach would be using tokenizer and then using NLTK to check synonyms of each word and map pairs to try out multiple phrasings to match the one we currently have, but it would take one too much time.

Is it possible to do this task using basic NLP?

Answer (score 0):

maybe an improvment of your first idea :

1. Split your keywords (chest_pain → ["chest","pain"]
2. Find only synonyms of your keywords ([["chest","thorax",...],["pain","suffer",...]]
3. For each words of your sentence check if the word is present in your keywords synonyms.

Comment: I'll try this. I feel like an idiot right now.